# Python: Expression returns Different Response a=a+1 vs a+=1

Tags: python, operators

**Note: I know python is strongly typed and we wont concatenate 2 different types. but accidentally i have tried**,

I got different result,

```
a = []
>>>a=a+1 #it gives me expected concatenate error
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list


>>>a+=1 #but this wasn't
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I don't see anything weird? The two messages are different, but they are referring to the same type error

Comment: a+=1 says type error: int is not iterable. but a=a+1 says type error : cannot concate 2 different types

Comment: and why can't you concatenate an `int` type to list? because it's not iterable

Comment: @turtle you wont concatenate list with int .. which happens when a=a+1
but a+=1 produces different says int is not iterable

Comment: *list concatenation* only accepts list objects, not arbitrary iterables. However, the `+=` operator, whose hook is the dunder method `__iadd__`,  unlike `__add__`, for lists is essentially `.extend`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because operator + and operator += is not same magic function implement in list class.

```py
__iadd__() ## Map to += Operator
__add__() ## Map to + Operator
```

That means you trigger different magic function of list object.

Comment: What is a magic function? How does triggering a different magic function change the error type?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh by magic function they mean a "dunder" method, i.e. `__len__` or `__add__` and `__iadd__` in this case. It changes the error because they are implemented differently.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather while doing experimentation is that.

1. `a = a + 1` is concatenating a list and an integer, but as we know `+` operator or concatenation requires two lists, hence the error we get is 
   `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "range") to list`, as we can see below

```
In [43]: [] + 1                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-67dee89361ae> in <module>
----> 1 [] + 1

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
In [47]: [] + []                                                                
Out[47]: []
```

2. In `a += 1`, we internally call `a.extend(1)` as per the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

> s.extend(t) or s += t .
>   extends s with the contents of t (for the most part the same as s[len(s):len(s)] = t)

Also from the docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.extend(iterable)
>   Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.

So `1` is being treated as an iterable, but since int is not an iterable, we get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` as we can see below

```
In [49]: a = []                                                                 

In [50]: a.extend(1)                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-4671950943e4> in <module>
----> 1 a.extend(1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Checking it? Do you mean accepting the answer @SilentSpectator

Comment: "1 is being tried to be converted to a list, and then being concatenated, " No, that isn't what is happening. Rather, `__iadd__` calls `.extend` under the hood and that is the source of the error.  As a consequence `+=` works with any iterable, unlike `+` which requires another list.

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga, I could not find any docs which says that! Could you please point me to the same?

Comment: I cannot find it in the docs, but [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee0309f3d83ab9ffa02542bcf45ece84f4fb265e/Objects/listobject.c#L996) is the CPython source code.

Comment: It is hinted at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) although a little obscure and not really directly.

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks a lot for the docs! I have updated my answer after your suggestions! Please check if my answer makes more sense now ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated the two operators do not map to the same magic function. And the two have different implementations. This has some interesting consequences. the normal plus (`+` or `__add__`) expects another list to concatenate whereas in-place add (`+=` or `__iadd__`) is more allowing and can take any iterator and make it into a list before adding:

```
a = []
a = a + range(2)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "range") to list

a += range(2)
[0, 1]
```

I don't know *why* this is though.

Comment: this will work in python2 in python 3,  range(3)  will give range object instead of []

Comment: @SilentSpectator No, this will giva a list also in Python 3. The base type is a list, and it would be strange if that turned into a range with an in place add.

Comment: @SilentSpectator Or do you mean that the addition will work in Python 2. Sure, since there the range will turn into a list.